# Browser not detecting .gzip files compressed with Compression-Webpack-Plugin and uploaded vis AWS Webpack-S3-Plugin

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, webpack

I see that the .gz files are being created in our AWS S3 bucket. However, when deploying the files to our production environment it just loads the uncompressed files.

Below is our webpack.prod file.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const isDevelopment = false;
const S3Plugin = require('webpack-s3-plugin');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

const BUCKET = `spotfund-responsive--${process.env.APP_ENV.toLowerCase()}`;
const S3 = {
  BUCKET,
  ROOTPATH: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/${BUCKET}/`,
};

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
  },
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    index: './src/index.jsx',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
      },
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        test: /\.yaml$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'json-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'yaml-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'styles'), path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'components')],
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: `css-loader!sass-loader${
            isDevelopment ? '?outputStyle=expanded&sourceMap=true&sourceMapContents=true' : ''
          }`,
        }),
        test: /\.scss|sass?$/,
      },
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|css)$/,
      },
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        test: /\.(ttf|eot)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=50000&mimetype=application/font-woff',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name]-[hash].js',
    publicPath: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ? S3.ROOTPATH : '/',
  },
  // optimization: {
  //   minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin()],
  // },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
      context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      manifest: require('./public/vendor-manifest.json'),
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
      },
      X_BUNDLE_SECRET: JSON.stringify(process.env.X_BUNDLE_SECRET),
      X_SHORTY_CODE: JSON.stringify(process.env.X_SHORTY_CODE),
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name]-[hash].css',
    }),
    new CompressionPlugin({
      test: /\.(js|css)$/,
      filename: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      deleteOriginalAssets: true,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      env: {
        APP_ENV: process.env.APP_ENV,
        ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV,
      },
      template: 'index.ejs',
      title: 'spotfund',
      favicon: 'favicon.ico',
      dllPath: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ? S3.ROOTPATH : '/',
    }),
    new ManifestPlugin(),
    process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      ? new S3Plugin({
          exclude: /.*\.html$/,
          s3Options: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region: 'us-east-1',
          },
          s3UploadOptions: {
            Bucket: S3.BUCKET,
            ContentEncoding(fileName) {
              if (/\.gz/.test(fileName)) {
                return 'gzip';
              }
            },
            ContentType(fileName) {
              if (/\.css/.test(fileName)) {
                return 'text/css';
              }
              if (/\.js/.test(fileName)) {
                return 'text/javascript';
              }
            },
          },
        })
      : () => {},
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      actions: path.join(__dirname, '/src/redux/actions'),
      components: path.join(__dirname, '/src/components'),
      reducers: path.join(__dirname, '/src/redux/reducers'),
      shared: path.join(__dirname, '/src/shared'),
      src: path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.css', '.json'],
  },
};
```

This is the template that we deploy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= manifest['index.css']%>" />
    <title>
      <%= title %>
    </title>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/spotfund/images/Favicon-2021-v2.png" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      history.scrollRestoration = 'manual';
      window.ENV = <%- JSON.stringify(ENV); %>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= cdnRoot %><%= manifest['vendor.js']%>"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= manifest['index.js']%>"></script>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

We think the compression is working as the gz files appear during the deployment process. I'm not sure I've to change the filename in our index.html template to reflect the js.gz name OR if I've to change the filename during the upload process.